# Correct approach for websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, websocket, socket.io

I'm building an application and would like to know what the correct approach would be for using websockets to deliver in app live notifications.

My app uses Express, Socket IO & Mongodb. I use Passport JS to authenticate users and something called [passportSocketIo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport.socketio) to connect Passport and Socket IO together.

The functionality I would like to have is shared notifications. Basically when there are several users all part of a group and one of the users updates something to do with the group, I want all users that belong to that group to receive the notification through web sockets.

My main question is should all these users share the same websocket in order to all receive the same notification? IE if someone connects to the group then I set the group websocket id to their websocket id then any following people that connect would assume that id too in order to have everyone on the same socket

OR

Should I store the users websocket id on every time they open a websocket connection with my app and store it in Mongo db say under the group model perhaps like so:

```
activeSocketIds:['id1','id2', etc...]
```

And whenever a change happens to the group, it goes and find the activeSocketIds in that group and pings all unique id's a message which will of course be the notification.

Maybe both of these are not the correct approach but would love some advice on what would be!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using SocketIO, you could use SocketIO's room functionality for your groups.

https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

If you use the SocketIO rooms, when a message or a notification needs to go out you could broadcast the notification, which would be sent to all clients connected to that room.

If your users are part of multiple groups, you can also subscribe to multiple rooms!